# Linux log management and compression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, sed

We run over system overnight for testing stability - since we need all the clue we need we also have the logs running overnight. The problem is the logs accumulate to several GBs over the night.

The log is currently captured as follows:
myProg > log.txt

I want to do the following:

1. Once the size of log.txt exceeds a configured size it is zipped as a separate zip file
2. I would like a timestamp (date and time the file was created) on the name of the zip file

e.g. If my logs were of 1 GB size and configured size limit was 100 MB, at the end of the test I will have following files
file1_timestamp.gz, file2_timestamp.gz, ... file10_timestamp.gz , where each of the .gz files will be of 100 MB size

1. The log should continue to come on stdout

Kindly provide your inputs

Thanks!

Comment: what is available as option (modify your script, a scheduled extra batch, other application, ...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logrotate` is the tool for the job.  Check out http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Comment: Thanks a ton! logrotate is a beauty :)